# Find lowest combination of values

Tags: php, find

I have a table like this:

```
Name | Skill
Joe  | 21
Moe  | 83
Doe  | 71
Noe  | 44
Zoe  | 67
Noe  | 33
```

Using PHP I want to generate two groups (they will be soccer teams) and find 3 combinations with the lowest skill difference, what I mean is that the teams should be as equal as possible based on skill points.

How can I do this?

Comment: Why don't you order by skill and then group the result ?

Comment: I guess this question would be better/faster answered on http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I guess it is, but just to make sure, are the team supposed to be of the same size (The best combination could be a 2-man team vs a 3-man team)?

Comment: yes the size should be the same. It's either 5vs5 or 6vs6 usually.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming your info is stored in an array $info of the form

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [name] => Joe
            [skill] => 21
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [name] => Moe
            [skill] => 83
        )

)
```

Then you just want to take a cartesian product of the arrays, ignoring self comparisons and duplicates:

```
$skill_differences = array();
foreach ($info as $first) {
    foreach ($info as $second) {
        if (strcmp($first['name'], $second['name']) > 0) {
            $skill_differences[] = array(
              'name1'=>$first['name'],
              'name2'=>$second['name'],
              'diff'=>abs($first['skill']-$second['skill'])
            );
        }
    }
}
```

NB: This assumes player names are unique. If they are not, then you will need to give each player a unique identifier and use that in place of `name`.

Then we can order the array by skill differences between players:

```
function skill_cmp ($a, $b) {
    return $a['diff'] - $b['diff'];
}
usort($skill_differences, 'skill_cmp');
```

so the three lowest skill difference pairings will be the first 3 elements in the `$skill_differences` array.